# add link to the selected image

Tags: jquery, html, css

in this code i am trying to find  what to change so as to add a differnet link in each image each time is selected for preview.

http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/3d-card-previewer/

http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/3d-card-previewer-9.29.14/

```
      <div class="container">
  <div class="card-container">
     <div class="card">
     <a href=""><img src="img/interstellar.jpg"></a>
     </div>
     </div>
  <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
    <a href=""><img src="img/imitation_game.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card-container">
    <div class="card">
    <a href=""><img src="img/hobbit.jpg"></a>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="card-container">
<div class="card">
     <a href=""><img src="img/boxtrolls.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="card-container active">
     <div class="card">
    <a href=""><img src="img/maze_runner.jpg"></a>
   </div>
   </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Link to some site is not useful. You should provide  minimal, complete and verifiable example. If you didn't try anything - try something and then ask specific question about what went wrong in your code.

Comment: @Regent I didn't seen it. you can edit further :)

Comment: @PandiyanCool I voted to close question, so I don't edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div.card > a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'the/new/path/to/preview');
    // ....
});
```

Comment: thanx for the answer / sorry for the links